# How to use mixin vuejs variables(constants) in the other js files?

Tags: vue.js, constants

I tried to use mixins in vuejs project and I could use constants in .vue files but not in .js files.
(I would like to define constants in the myMixin.js file because of using it in vue file also.)

```
// myMixin.js

const ROLES = {
  admin: 'ADMIN'
},
const OPTIONS = {
  ...
}

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      ROLES: ROLES,
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

```
// main.js

import myMixin from '@/common/myMixin' 
...

Vue.mixin(myMixin)
...
```

```
// router.js

...
if(store.state.account.role !== ROLES.admin) { // ROLES.admin: NOT WORKING HERE.
   next('/403')
}
...
```

```
// Header.vue

<template>
  <v-list-group
    :value='false'
    no-action
    v-if='$store.state.account.role === ROLES.admin'   // working perfectly

...
</template>
```

Comment: I think you shoud export like this `return { ROLES }`

Comment: @David Oh, sorry. I edited. It was { ROLES: ROLES }. But not working...

Answer (score 0):

You should `export` those constants from the mixin module so you can `import` them into other plain JavaScript modules to use.

```es6
// myMixin.js

export const ROLES = {
  admin: 'ADMIN'
}

export const OPTIONS = {
  ...
}

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      roles: ROLES,
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

```es6
// router.js

import { ROLES } from './myMixin.js'

...
if (store.state.account.role !== ROLES.admin) {
  next('/403')
}
...
```

If you don't like the idea of importing the constants into every module, then you can assign them onto the global context (`window`) which will make them available globally, but this defeats the purpose of using modules in the first place and I don't recommend it.

```es6
// myMixin.js

window.ROLES = {
  admin: 'ADMIN'
}

window.OPTIONS = {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, it doens't work. I tried to import variable ways as possible as I can but it returns 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it but I am not certain that it is a correct way.
Please share me, if you have better ideas.

```
// router.js

import myMixin from '@/common/myMixin'

console.log(myMixin.data().ROLES.admin)   // 'ADMIN'
if(store.state.account.role !== myMixin.data().ROLES.admin) {
   next('/403')
}
...
```